# How to run spark java with Kotlin from command line

Tags: gradle, kotlin, spark-java

I am newish to Java (haven't done it in probably 7 years). I am using Gradle, with [spark-java](http://sparkjava.com/) to create a simple hello world application that just runs this:

```
import static spark.Spark.*;

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  get("/hello", (req, res) -> "Hello World!");
}
```

In eclipse I can do this by getting the gradle plugin and starting a new gradle project. But there are also "Kotlin" projects. So you can't start a new gradle project with kotlin.

What I am trying to grok is the fact that with JavaScript and Node I normally do everything by command line. I would like to build this project and run the server from the command line with Gradle, but I am not sure how to do this.

This is my current build.gradle:

```
// Apply the kotlin plugin to add support for Kotlin
apply plugin: 'kotlin'

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2-4'

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.kotlin.srcDirs += 'src/main/myKotlin'
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/myJava'
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.1.2-4'
    }
}

// In this section you declare where to find the dependencies of your project
repositories {
    // Use 'jcenter' for resolving your dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    jcenter()
}

// In this section you declare the dependencies for your production and test code
dependencies {
    // The production code uses the SLF4J logging API at compile time
    compile 'com.sparkjava:spark-core:2.3'

    // Declare the dependency for your favourite test framework you want to use in your tests.
    // TestNG is also supported by the Gradle Test task. Just change the
    // testCompile dependency to testCompile 'org.testng:testng:6.8.1' and add
    // 'test.useTestNG()' to your build script.
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

I run `gradle` on the command line and it builds successfully but how would I start the server so I can go to `localhost:4567` and see my `Hello World` output? What is the general flow I should be following?

To be clear: I am making a conscience decision to use Kotlin instead of Java.

Comment: @Aaron I do want to use Kotlin. Updated question.

Comment: Seems like you need to refer to the Gradle documentation

Comment: By the way, you did not need srcDirs. The default of `src/main/kotlin` would be fine

Comment: dupes also cover running from gradle.